# Kong load balance where upstream has different root paths?

Tags: load-balancing, kong, nginx-upstreams

I'm using Kong OSS (not container or k8s deployed) trying to load balance a backend two backend services for testing. My challenge is one requires authentication and different backend path port, whereas the other does not.

**Frontend 1 - Kong API Gateway frontend**

- Host: localhost
- Port: 8000
- Authentication: none
- Root Path: /
- Example Request: POST http://localhost:8000/ {JSON Data}

I'm expecting this front-end to have following backend

**Backend A - local API service for testing**

- Host: localhost
- Port: 80
- Authentication: none
- Root Path: /
- Example Request: POST http://localhost:80/ {JSON Data}

**Backend B - hosted SaaS API service**

- Host: s1.example.com
- Port: 443
- Authentication: API Key
- Root Path: /v7/guid/
- Example Request:  POST https://s1.example.com/v7/guid/ {JSON Data}

Following the documentation, it seems I need to create 1 service to 2 upstream/targets, but not sure how to handle different upstream root paths?
[image: Kong Load Balancing]

Can the upstream config dynamically change the backend path based on selected upstream/target? Or maybe instead create a single route that load-balances between two services?

I'm trying to create 1 route with 1 service that has 2 upstream targets with different root paths and request-transformers for specific upstream targets

Comment: You cannot root based on the listening port see https://github.com/Kong/kong/discussions/7273

Comment: I'm not trying to route based on port. I'm trying to change the backend route prefix based on selected target, while backends can live on different ports, they apparently must have the same root url path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two services, each service with one route. Both routes uses the same path,

Service 1: http://httpbin.org

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8001/services/' \
--form 'name="httpbin"' \
--form 'url="http://httpbin.org"'
```

Route 1: /path

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8001/services/httpbin/routes/' \
--form 'paths[]="/testPath"' \
--form 'name="httpbinget"' \
--form 'hosts[]="httpbin.org"'
```

Service 2: http://mockbin.org

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8001/services/' \
--form 'name="mockbin-secure"' \
--form 'url="https://mockbin.org"'
```

Route 2: /testpath

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8001/services/mockbin-secure/routes/' \
--form 'paths[]="/testPath"' \
--form 'name="mockbin-get"' \
--form 'hosts[]="mockbin.org"'
```

Test the API Gateway proxy /testPath

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8000/testPath/' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.yang.data+json' \
--header 'Host: httpbin.org'

curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8000/testPath/' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.yang.data+json' \
--header 'Host: mockbin.org'
```

The 2nd request is expected to fail if it requires authentication, the last step will be to enable authentication plugin on this particular service

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/services/mockbin-secure/plugins \
    --data "name=key-auth"  \
    --data "config.key_names=apikey" \
    --data "config.key_in_body=false" \
    --data "config.key_in_header=true" \
    --data "config.key_in_query=true" \
    --data "config.hide_credentials=false" \
    --data "config.run_on_preflight=true"
```

the apikey needs to be provided when testing the proxy

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8000/testPath/' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.yang.data+json' \
--header 'Host: httpbin.org' \
--header 'api-key: somekey'
```

I don't have a secure service to test with now, I hope that might help.